# showing that a multivariate function is not continuous at the origin, although Wolfram Alpha says it is

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

I am being asked to show that the following function is NOT continuous at the origin.

$f(x,y) =\begin{cases}\frac{x^4y^5}{x^8 + y^{10}} &&(x,y) \not= (0,0) \\0 &&(x,y) = (0,0) \end{cases}$

Thus, I've tried to show that the following limit does not equal to zero, with different paths $y=mx, y=x^2$, and so forth, but without success.

$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{x^4y^5}{x^8 + y^{10}}$

Eventually I checked with Wolfram Alpha, and it computed that the limit is indeed 0, as I have suspected, so I figured there might be some mistake in the exercise... In fact, the whole exercise is to show that even though the function is not continuous at the origin, its partial derivatives exist. 
I have had several exercises like this, where Wolfram contradicted what I was asked to prove. And I know that Wolfram has been wrong before, so I would appreciate some help in the matter - Is Wolfram wrong, or the exercise?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try $y=x^{\frac{5}{4}}$

Comment: Sorry, I still got 0 from both of your suggestions. Lord Shark, I got $\frac{t^{20}y^{20}}{t^{40} + y^{40}}$ and when $t \to 0$ the limit is still 0. I am probably doing something wrong. Would you mind elaborate?

Comment: Try $(x,y)=(t^5,t^4)$ and let $t\to0$. With Wolfram Alpha you get what you pay for!

Comment: Now I get it. Thanks for the clarification. I understand I should look for paths where I will get the same degree in both parts of the fraction. As I actually pay a small sum for the pro account on Wolfram, it is really rather annoying...

Comment: I think what sahiba meant was $y=x^{4/5}$